# using wildcards in <xsl:match="myTag*">

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to create an xsl template that will accept wildcards as part of the template match as the following example will show:

```
<xsl:template match="*_Nokia_5.0">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is 'match any tag that has 'Nokia_5.0' as part of the string.
Is there any way I can do this in xslt 1.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `contains(name(), "Nokia_5.0")` is not the solution, as it will return false positives on names like:

```
myNokia_5.0isAwsome
```

however the requirement is that the name must *end* with the string `'Nokia_5.0'`.

---

**A correct solution**:

**In XSLT 2.0**:

```
<xsl:template match="*[ends-with(name(), 'Nokia_5.0')]">
```

**In XSLT 1.0**:

```
<xsl:template match=
 "*[substring(name(), string-length(name()) -8) = 'Nokia_5.0')]">
```

Comment: @рüффп You are welcome! Yes, XPath and XSLT are wonderful languages. One can learn a lot more here: https://www.pluralsight.com/library/courses/xslt-foundations-part1/table-of-contents

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the node name must contain the given string, you can use contains()

```
<xsl:template match='*[contains(name(), "Nokia_5.0")]'>
```

However this would mean that any nodes that DON'T conform to this requirement lack a template, and would be output as-is if you applied templates to all nodes.

Instead, you could make the filter stipulation not in the template definition but at the point of applying templates.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select='node[contains(name(), "Nokia_5.0")]' />
....
<xsl:template match='node'>
    <xsl:value-of select='.' />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thant doesn't seem to work - it does not recognise the node <WPA_Nokia_5.0> at all.  I've inserted your second example as it closely matches what I'd like to do.

Comment: Resovled it : [contains(**name()**, "Nokia_5.0")]

Comment: Oh so you meant the name of the node... I'll update my answer nonetheless

Comment: Of course, using only `contains()` isn't enough as returns `true()` not only for substrings that end the name. One must use an equivalent of `ends-with()`.

Comment: I'm using XPath 1.0 so ends-with is not an option.

Comment: In 1.0 you can always use contains(concat(name(), '§'), 'Nokia_5.0§') as a workaround for the absence of ends-with().

Comment: @yorkshireflatcap: I said "an equivalent of `ends-with()`" -- and this means a substitute for XSLT 1.0 -- exactly what is in my answer.